# For loops in Dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to use a **for loop in a dictionary** to represent an unknown about of statements that may need to be in the dictionary (based on the specified amount when stating the class). I was wondering what the syntax for that would be if there is any at all.

Earlier today a friend asked me to make a **Choose Your Own Adventure game**.

- I wanted to have a random page be the death page.
- The rest of the pages are story/question pages.
- I also wanted to have a dictionary that when I put in a page number
  it returned the type of page it was.

> I was trying to use a `for` statement to get a page number that is
>   called with the class. The pages are random so there is no way for me
>   to know.

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def ClearSys():
  for i in range(0,100):
    print("\n")
class Book:
  def __init__(self,name,pages):

    #self.DeathPage#
    RandomPage=randint(2,pages)
    self.DeathPage=RandomPage
    del RandomPage

    #self.pages#
    self.pages=["Introduction Page"]
    for i in range(2,pages):
      if not i==self.DeathPage:
        self.pages.append("QuestionPage")
      else:
        self.pages.append("DeathPage")



    ####MAIN SECTION I WOULD LIKE TO HIGHLIGHT####
    ##Page number dictionary##
    self.PageNumberToType={
      0:"Introduction Page",
      for i in range(1,len(self.pages)):
        i:self.pages[i]
    }
    ########
```

I didn't really expect this to work, but I just wrote it out to see if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of; but why does it need to be inside the dictionary literal?

```
self.PageNumberToType = { 0:"Introduction Page" }

for i in range(1, len(self.pages)):
    self.PageNumberToType[i] = self.pages[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because order is of little importance when it comes to dictionaries, you can do a dictionary-comprehension as well:

```
self.PageNumberToType = {i: self.pages[i]
                         for i in range(1, len(self.pages[i]))}

self.PageNumberToType.update({0: 'Introduction Page'})
```